# Why is the Max function so slow when operating on lists of dates?

Tags: performance-tuning

Example:

```
dates = DateRange[DateObject[], DatePlus[DateObject[], 15]];
First[AbsoluteTiming[Max[dates]]]

(* 21.364247 *)
```

As a workaround, `DateObject[Max[AbsoluteTime /@ dates]]` will get the same result much faster, but I'm just curious to know what's going on under the hood to justify all that computation time.

```
First[AbsoluteTiming[DateObject[Max[AbsoluteTime /@ dates]]]]

(* 0.015625 *)
```

Comment: Can't repoduce your problem. Version 10.1 gives 0.00141043 and 0.00216561 for your first and second command, respectively.

Comment: I can confirm, no significant slowdown on 10.1 on OS X.

Comment: However, the timings agree with OP in 10.0.2 on Linux.

Comment: There was a bug that caused `Max` and `Min` of expressions containing `DateObject` to be extremely slow. This bug was fixed in version 10.1.0.